# Codeigniter arabic changing to '????'

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, internationalization

I have a small web-app/utility built with Codeigniter that seems to have become quiet popular in Arabic speaking countries - currently however all Arabic writing is converted to question marks - how do I go about supporting Arabic? Data is inputted by the user which is then retrieved from a database for future display.

The data inputted by the user is stored and retrieved from a MYSQL database and jQuery is used to handle Ajax calls if that makes any difference.

Is this a PHP/Codeigniter issue or a MYSQl one? (or both?)

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's causing this. You need to make sure that your site uses the UTF-8 encoding all the way through. This generally amounts to ensuring that database connections are set to UTF-8 and that your PHP sends the correct UTF-8 header and/or meta tag with the HTML content.

Comment: @WillVousden ok, since I didn't put any thought in to UTF-8 when I built this site (getting on 2 years ago now) I'm going to say that UTF-8 isn't supported at all. Now I know what I'm looking for I'm guessing this is fairly well documented? Will changing now mess up my existing database content do you know?

Comment: It shouldn't do, but you may want to back it up just in case! There's a good guide to crafting a UTF-8-compliant web application here: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: The link in Varun's comment has the specifics for CodeIgniter, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a UTF-8 encoding meta tag while displaying content in arabic ?

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also please check here

http://osamaahmedattia.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/arabic-languages-in-codeigniter/

Comment: This on its own isn't sufficient. The HTTP `Content-Type` header should be used to specify the encoding; the meta tag is only used if this header is absent.

Comment: refer to this http://osamaahmedattia.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/arabic-languages-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @VarunSheth have marked as the answer but the link in your comment was actually what helped - maybe you want to edit and add that in?